# Replacement for `pwd` in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pwd

I have a Unix script which uses the command

```
Current_Dir=`pwd`
```

What would be the suitable replacement for it in Windows Power shell script?

Answer (score 17):

Both of these are valid if you are trying to make a var with your current dir:

```
$current_directory = (pwd).path
$current_directory = pwd
```

The development team for Powershell contains a couple of Unix guys, so there are some goodies in there like `ls`, `pwd` and `cat`

Answer (score 12):

Use the `$pwd.Path` expression

```
write-host $pwd.Path
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use "pwd", or "Get-Location" ("pwd" is just an alias for "Get-Location").

ALso: you don't need the quotes in PS, like you do in a Unix shell.

Answer (score 2):

> Powershell has many of the same commands as Linux. pwd is the command equivalent.
>   When you type pwd in Powershell, it is an alias to Get-Location.

https://superuser.com/questions/295021/windows-powershell-equivalent-to-unix-linux-pwd