# Why '.' not equals "$pwd" in [DirectoryInfo]

Tags: powershell

I have a function:

```
function foo {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]]$path
    )
    foreach ($p in $path) {
        Write-Host $p.FullName
    }
}
```

where '.' refers to the script's home directory instead of current directory.

```
PS D:\> foo .,"$pwd"      
D:\ps1
D:\
```

I want `foo .` returns `D:\` instead of `D:\ps1`, where the current directory is.

Comment: [`pwd`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21846161/1701026) refers to the current path, [`PSScriptRoot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466329/1701026) refer to "*the script's home directory*".

Comment: See also: [about automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

Comment: @iRon Maybe my original question isn't clear enough, I want `foo .` returns current directory. But it in fact returns `PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: In my case, I get indeed the same results for `.` and `"$pwd" `. Anyways, I have reopened the issue.

Comment: @iRon I also found that `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'.'` will return the path where pwsh is opened, so maybe that's why. Perhaps I need to use `[string]` instead then replace with `$pwd`.

Comment: It's .Net `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` because you're using `IO.FileInfo` to resolve a relative path